# how to parse smt2 commands using z3 api c++?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, z3

I want to use `api_parsers` in `z3 api` to parse `smt2` commands and then I want to see the contents of resulted `vectors`(like sorts, variables, params , ...).

but I don't how? I write a piece of code like below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<z3++.h>
#include<z3_api.h>

using namespace z3;

int main() {
context ctx;    
//z3_string fname = ;
Z3_ast a = Z3_parse_smtlib2_file(ctx, "smt_z3.smt2", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
expr e(ctx, a);
std::cout << "result = " <<e << std::endl;

return 0;
```

and run it in ubuntu( I have installed z3 in ubuntu earlier)and then I received errors like this  after running command: `g++ -o parser_api z3_api_parser_tst.cpp`

[image: Error]

how can I acheive my goal? is my code appropriate for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Answer (score 1):

This looks like standard linking errors. You need to link with z3lib/libz3.
Your call to the parser is otherwise right.